# How to display HTML in JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am developing a FontViewer application which changes the font of the text based on the selected font style.

This is the controller class of my application

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView fontListView;

    @FXML
    private TextArea fontTextArea;

    int[] fontSizes = {34, 28, 24, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6};

    String fontText = "";

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ObservableList<String> fontsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFontNames());
        fontListView.setItems(fontsList);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleMouseClickEvent(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        changeFont();
    }

    public void changeFont() {
        for (int i = 0; i < fontSizes.length; i++) {
            fontText += "<p style='font-family:" + fontListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() + ";font-size:" + fontSizes[i] + "'>" + "This is Sample Text</p>";
        }

        fontTextArea.setText(fontText);
    }
}
```

Screenshot of my application:

[image]

When I use a `TextArea`, it displays just the plain HTML code instead of converting the HTML to Text. Which control should I use to accomplish this?

P.S: I tried `TextFlow` but it doesn't work, as I need to display different Styles and font-sizes for the required text.

I also looked at `WebView` but didn't understand how it could solve the mentioned problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a web view:

```
@FXML
private WebView fontWebView ;

// ...

public void changeFont() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fontText);
    for (int i = 0; i < fontSizes.length; i++) {
        sb.append("<p style='font-family:")
          .append(fontListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem())
          .append(";font-size:")
          .append( fontSizes[i])
          .append("'>This is Sample Text</p>");
    }
    fontText = sb.toString();
    fontWebView.getEngine().loadContent(fontText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late answer, but I wanted to pass this along for those who need to apply fonts to a variety of FX controls (as I needed to do):

You can display fonts without using a `WebView`, by using the `TextArea`'s setFont method. This has the advantage of being applicable to most text displaying FX controls, including `Button`, `TextField`, etc..., and can be used with downloaded TTF or OTF files.

```
// examples create a 20 pt font
// system font
Font f = Font.font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 20);
// TTF/OTF added to your project as a resource:
Font f = Font.loadFont(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ResourceName"), 20);
// TTF/OTF loaded from a file dynamically... read the font file into an input stream, and:
Font f = Font.loadFont(inputStream, 20);
// to use:
fontTextArea.setFont(f);
```

Note: some of the script TTF/OTF fonts can extend above or below the area that a system font will fit into, so test appropriately when using downloaded fonts.