# How to add superscript to Label text in Javafx 8

Tags: java, javafx, jlabel, superscript

I am writing my first JavaFX application and I cannot find how to make some of the text in a Label to be superscript.

In Swing it was easy enough to use HTML tags, but this option is not available in JavaFX.

I have searched through many of the api's including Label, Font, TextFlow, Oracle docs and samples, and the internet in general.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WebView` is more flexible, but, depending upon which font you are using and the content of the superscript, there are [Unicode superscript characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) such as `U+00B2` for the superscript 2.

Comment: Thank you clartaq. I realise now that I could have also used Unicode for JLabel as well. I have been using Unicode to produce Registered Trade Mark and Copyright symbols, however, I was unaware of Unicode superscript.

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to substitute a [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and use the `loadContent()` method of [`WebEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.loadContent(
    "<h1>G<sub>&mu;&nu;</sub>=8πT<sub>&mu;&nu;</sub>; E=mc<sup>2</sup>");
```

[image]

Comment: See also [*How to display HTML in JavaFX Application*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30829164/230513).